# TextView not drawn when doing invalidate()

Tags: android, view, invalidation

I'm trying to display views which coordinates on screen depends on sensors data. I managed to show a text as explained in [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708943/updating-child-views-position-into-parent-view-according-to-sensors-data) and I'm now trying to show some TextViews instead, but when calling invalidate() on my TextViews, they're not drawn...

Anybody can help?

Thanks

**ARView.java**

```
public class ARView extends TextView
{ 
    public String name;
    public float azimuth;
    public float distance;
    public float inclination;
    public Location location;

    public ARView(Context context)
    {        
        super(context);
        setText(name);
    }
}
```

**ARActivity.java**

Here I add my ARView to its parent view.

```
public class ARActivity extends Activity{

    private ARLayout ar;
    private CBCameraView cv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ar = new ARLayout(getApplicationContext());

            cv = new CBCameraView(this.getApplicationContext());

            FrameLayout rl = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());

            rl.addView(cv, GlobalVars.screenWidth, GlobalVars.screenHeight); 
            rl.addView(ar, GlobalVars.screenWidth, GlobalVars.screenHeight); 

            setContentView(rl);

            Location location = new Location("me");
            location.setLatitude(41.371974);
            location.setLongitude(2.166978);

            ARView fs = new ARView(this.getApplicationContext());
            fs.azimuth = 0;
            fs.inclination = 0;
            fs.location = location;
            fs.name="Bar seco";
            ar.addARView(fs);                    
    }
}
```

**ARLayout.java**

Here I get sensors data, update my ARViews coordinates and hopefully draw them...

```
public class ARLayout extends View implements LocationListener, SensorEventListener
{

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        // here I get sensors data and update my views

        for(int i=0; i<nArViews; i++)
        {

            ARView view = arViews.get(i);            

            int x = ...; // new x coordinate of my ARView
            int y = ...; // new y coordinate of my ARView

            view.layout(x, y, view.getBottom(), view.getRight());  // set new coordinates to my ARViews

        }

        invalidate(); // draw my ARLayout       
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<nArViews; i++)
        {                
            ARView view = arViews.get(i);
            view.invalidate();  // I thought it would draw my ARViews, but it doesn't :(
        }
    }

    // more stuff   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the solution to the specific problem, but I do know this is another problem.

Remove the `invalidate()` call in the `onDraw()` method.  You only need to call invalidate once per draw.  Removing it from `onDraw()` will ensure the screen only updates when you have new sensor data.  The screen won't actually draw until `onDraw()` leaves as well.

Alternatively, you can move the call to `invalidate()` AFTER the for-loop in `onDraw()` and remove it entirely from `onSensorChanged()`.  This will make the screen constantly redraw whether you have sensor data or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are only changing the view's positions. You don't have to call invalidate and you don't have to overrule onDraw. For those kind of things the OS knows when to redraw. Invalidate and onDraw is for custom drawing only.